# Math column in tabular without "array" package

Tags: math-mode, tables

I'd like to do something like

```
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} c}
```

but I'm not able to use the `array` package (which defines `>{...}` and `<{...}`) due to technical restrictions.

Is there any simple way I can achieve this?

Comment: What technical restrictions?

Comment: Have to upload a file to a remote server in order to submit it and I'm not allowed to change the preamble. :\

Comment: This may sound like real skulduggery, but could you just cut and paste all (or at least the relevant portions) of the code of array.sty into the first part of the body of your document, sandwiching it between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`? You would have to comment out the `\CheckCommand*` instruction, though, as such an instruction is only allowed in the preamble...

Comment: I guess that the only way is to add `$` to the entries of the table. If you're not allowed to change the preamble, probably they won't be fond of some strange code in the document.

Comment: @egreg: the only other option I see is to use `\newenvironment{mytablecc}{\halign\bgroup\hfil$#$\hfil&\hfil#\hfil\cr}{\crcr\egroup}`, which hard-codes the preamble (or use the `\halign` directly in the text).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Of course, but I doubt that the strict rules about the preamble will allow for such a solution.

Answer (score 5):

(Making an answer from my comment)

I guess that the only way is to add `$` to the entries of the table. If you're not allowed to change the preamble, probably they won't be fond of some strange code in the document.